# How to load more ajax data refering to the post ID, fetched with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1. I have a **"img_title"** list. The 'img_title' getting fetched **via php** from database - dynamic list.

   ```
   +------------------------+
   | img_title:             |
   +========================+
   | golden Retriever       |
   +------------------------+
   | Appenzeller Sennenhund |
   +------------------------+
   | German Shepard         |
   +------------------------+
   | Alaskan Klee Kai       |
   +------------------------+
   |       . . . . .        |
   +------------------------+
   ```
2. If the user clicks on a **"img_title" ...**

   ```
   +-----------------------------+
   |<b>Appenzeller Sennenhund</b>|     
   +-----------------------------+
   ```
3. ... then should show up a new div box with the **"img_descr"** separately and fetched **via AJAX**:

   ```
   +-----------------------------+     +-----------------------------+
   |   Appenzeller Sennenhund    |     |<b>Swiss: ABC123...      </b>| 
   +-----------------------------+     +-----------------------------+
   ```

   ... or

   ```
   +-----------------------------+     +-----------------------------+
   |   golden Retriever          |     |<b>UK: ZYX987...         </b>|
   +-----------------------------+     +-----------------------------+
   ```

I need a connection between the php fetched data and the ajax fetched data.

I only know how to fetch all description at once but not how to fetch "img_title - ID:3" (php) with only "img_descr - ID:3" (ajax).

I thought about to fetch also the "img_id" and refering to that, ajax could fetch more data from database.

Here is my code (without img_id connection between php & ajax fetched data)

HTML & PHP:

```
<body>

  <?php
     $db     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
     $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        echo "<button class='img_title'>Title: <b>" . $row['img_title'] . "</b></button><br>";
     }
   ?>

   <div id="descrs"></div>

</body>
```

**JavaScrpit & AJAX**

```
 <script>
   // Get the buttons (NodeList)
   var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button.img_title");

   for(var x=0; x < buttons.length; x++) {
     buttons[x].addEventListener('click', loadDescr);
   }

 function loadDescr(e)
 {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.php', true);

    xhr.onload = function()
    {
       if (this.status == 200)
       {
         var descrs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

         var output = '';

         for (var i in descrs) {
           output += '<ul>' +
               '<li class="ajax_img_descr">ID: ' + descrs[i].img_descr + '</li>' +  '</ul>';
         }

         document.getElementById('descrs').innerHTML = output;
     }
   }
   xhr.send();
 }
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
// Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'xy');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM images';
// Get Result
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// Fetch Data
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($users);
?>
```

Comment: Add `ID` as an attribute to a `button`, get this attribute in JS, pass it to php and use it in a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to pass ID to server, you somehow should store it in a `button`, the simpliest way is to use `data`-attribute:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo "<button class='img_title' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>Title: <b>" . $row['img_title'] . "</b></button><br>";
 }
```

Next, you have to get this data-id in event handler. It can be done via `getAttribute` function:

```
function loadDescr(e)
{
    var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    // console.log(id);    // for testing purposes

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax.php?id=' + id, true);

    // more codes

}
```

On serverside your id is available via `$_GET['id']`:

```
<?php
// Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'xy');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id']; // I simplified this code, but you MUST use prepared statements here to avoid sql-injection
// Get Result
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
// Fetch Data
$users = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($users);
?>
```